# Different types RxSwift

Tags: rx-swift

I don't know how to map custom types. I have two variables with custom types -

var viewModel: PurchaseList.Fetch.ViewModel?
var response: PurchaseList.Fetch.Response?

```
    struct Response: Mappable {
        var shoppingList : [ShoppingList]?
    }

    struct ShoppingList: Mappable {
    var name: String?
    var offers: [Offers]?
    }

    struct Offers {
    var fullPrice: String?
    }
```

and

```
struct ViewModel {
var name: String?
var offers: [ViewModelOffers]?
}

struct ViewModelOffers {
var fullPrice: String?
}
```

how I can create  `var viewModel: PurchaseList.Fetch.ViewModel?` from `var response: PurchaseList.Fetch.Response?` using RxSwift?

Comment: are you sure you need Rx to solve this problem? maybe you should use Generic Types?

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik hi! How I can to do that?

Comment: I don't see any sense in your code, why don't you create a variable in your ViewModel of type ShoppingList to access offers as is your ViewModel duplicates ShoppingList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the types you presented, I'm guessing that you are looking for code something like the below. This code has a lot of accidental complexity because of the excessive use of Optionals (the `?`) in the types.

There is virtually no reason for Strings or Arrays to be optional. Logically, an empty string is no different than a nil string (and an empty array is no different than a nil array) in 99.99% of cases. As such, a strong argument would need to be presented to justify making them optional.

```
func example(_ from: Observable<Response?>) -> Observable<[ViewModel]?> {
    return from
        .map { $0?.shoppingList ?? [] }
        .map { $0.map{ $0.map(ViewModel.init) } }
}

extension ViewModel {
    init(_ shoppingList: ShoppingList) {
        name = shoppingList.name
        offers = shoppingList.offers?.map { ViewModelOffers(fullPrice: $0.fullPrice) }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm use optionals, because I work with ObjectMapper library

Comment: Only a couple of your types are `Mappable` but all of your types are using Optional. That's not a good enough reason to justify them IMHO.

Comment: Did I answer your question adequately?

Comment: So close... In my array, I have all Offers, but "name" of magazine is only one.

Comment: Based on the code in the question, there is a name for every ShoppingList object. You say there is only one name... Where does that come from?